# What happens if one thread fails in parallel gem

Tags: ruby

I'm using parallel gem for multithreading. Wondering what happens if one of the threads fails? Is it just ignored and does it impact other threads? I googled it and checked their documentation (https://github.com/grosser/parallel) but can't find an answer.

Comment: @lacostenycoder thx for suggestion, I updated question.

Comment: Worth writing a bit of test code to find out. In regular Ruby when a thread crashes nothing happens until you check with `join` or have `Thread.abort_on_exception = true` enabled.